# Ubuntu Software is not working/opening

Tags: software-center

When I'm trying to open Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.4 LTS it's not opening.
At the beginning it opens and I have updated some of my softwares like Mozilla Firefox but now it's not opening.

Comment: Have you tried open it from the console?. This will give you some idea about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic -y
```

Then use synaptic, it is more useful.

Comment: I disagree. And it does not fix his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Try start

> software-center

in terminal and show this output text. Maybe this is python glitches.